# reactjs presentation comopnent not re-rendering on redux state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, containers

**Situation**
I have a reactjs app using redux. I've got a container, and a presentation component. My presentation component renders a form with an array of simple text input fields, and I'm passing an 'onChange' callback function from the container to the presentation component which dispatches an action to change redux state when one of the text fields is typed in.

**Problem** 
The presentation component successfully renders the correct values for the text fields from redux state when the presentation component mounts, but doesn't update when I type in the fields. If I log the props that are passed  to the presentation component in `mapStateToProps` in the container, I can see that the onChange function is correctly dispatching to the store, and the redux state is being updated correctly. But the presentation component is not re-rendering when this happens, so typing in the text field doesn't update the view (typing does nothing).

**formConnector**

```
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import Form from '../components/Form'
    import { changeElementValue } from '../actions/actions'

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        //e.g. state.elements = [{id:"email", value:"foo@bar.com"}]
        let props = {
            elements: state.elements,
        }

        //state and props.elements.{id}.value changes successfully when I 
        //type in one of the input fields, but
        //the the Form component is not re-rendered
        console.log(props) 

        return props
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            onElementChange: (id, value) => {
                dispatch(changeElementValue(id, value))
            },
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Form)
```

**Form reducer**

```
    function formReducer(state = initialState, action = null) {
        switch(action.type) {
            case types.CHANGE_ELEMENT_VALUE:
                let newState = Object.assign({}, state)
                newState.elements[action.id].value = action.value
                return newState

            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
```

**actions**

```
    import * as types from './actionTypes'

    export function changeElementValue(id, value) {
        return { type: types.CHANGE_ELEMENT_VALUE, id, value }
    }
```

Comment: Can you attach the component code and the reducer? Are you sure that the store has changed? It seems like the value you are taking is set on the state.textField.value, and im not sure what the reducer changes (via id, and what id it passes). I bet the problem is in that area

Comment: @Kinnza Thanks for taking a look. I have a horrible feeling I've masked the problem in an effort to simplify the code for this post. My connector actually connects a 'Form' component which renders a set of text elements. So state  contains an array of id value pairs. I'll have a go at re-writing the example with code simple enough to paste here, but that I can run to ensure it replicates the issue. In the mean time - is it conceivable that my component is not recognising the state change because it's a change to a value buried in an array within the state? Should be using immutable?

Comment: OK, I've not had chance to build a prototype using my simplified code yet (will try later if necessary), but I have updated the example so that it's more representative of what is happening in my real app. Now there is an array of elements being rendered. Once again, what do you think of my hunch that that the presentation component (Form) is not being re-rendered because it's not detecting the change to state when one of the values in the elements array is updated?

Comment: @xanld You're right. Arrays are passed by ref, so even if you mutate the array (pushing, poping etc.), the reference will still stay the same and the changes won't be detected.

Comment: @OB3 sounds like this is the problem then. So how do I solve it? I've not used immutable - is this relevant? Or should I have a connector for each text field element individually? I can't imagine at the moment how to write that... Kinnza - apologies again for misleading you with my original post.

Comment: Using a library like Immutable.js is unnecessary, but you _should_ maintain the concept of immutability. That means that if you'd like to manipulate the array, you'd actually have to create a new array: `return [...state, {}]`. You would do the same if you wish to edit or remove an existing element in the array. This might help: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html

Comment: Exactly what @OB3 wrote. You will have to recreate your array in the reducer so the change will be marked.If you paste your reducer here i can try to help

Comment: Hi, I've just added the reducer and action code. Thanks again both for your help.

Comment: `Object.assign` is shallow, so you're actually mutating `state.elements` in your reducer. Even if you weren't, the reducer code seems to be wrong. You're assigning the new value to `newState.elements[action.id].value`, where `action.id` is a string, but `newState.elements` is an array of objects. I like to use the [seamless-immutable](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable) library for handling changes in my reducers, I suggest you take a look at it. Otherwise, it's a bit tedious and error-prone to do deep immutable operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this is due to state mutation.

Try to change your reducer code as follows:

```
case types.CHANGE_ELEMENT_VALUE: {
    const newElements = state.elements.map(function(el, index) {
        return action.id === index 
            ? Object.assign({}, el, { value: action.value }) 
            : el;
    });
    return Object.assign({}, state, { elements: newElements );
}
```

or more elegantly:

```
case types.CHANGE_ELEMENT_VALUE:
    return { ...state, elements: state.elements.map((el, index) => (
        action.id === index ? { ...el, value: action.value } : el
    )}
```

Comment: Hi, I marked this as the answer because it does answer my question. The root problem of which was that state returned contained references to the old state, so didn't react didn't detect a change. This answer has helped me identify this, and I'm very grateful to OB3 Kinnza and Assan. In actual fact, I bungled my code examples and my problem remains as I can't directly apply the solution here to my actual code. So I've reframed the problem more accurately in a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418623/change-value-deep-in-redux-state. Thanks again.