# change value deep in redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

**context**

I'm rendering a form with a dynamic set of text elements. I've normalised my state using [normalizr principles](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) so there is an array of elementIds and an object containing the element properties referenced by the elementIds (see initial state in code sample below).

**aim**

My aim is simply for the two rendered elements to be editable. I'm successfully dispatching an action CHANGE_ELEMENT_VALUE to my store using an onChange callback, and action.id (referencing the id of the changed element) and action.value (the new value) are available in the reducer (see code below).

**problem**

My problem is that the text fields aren't changing when I type, even though I can see state changing using the devtools redux extension. My understanding is that react is not recognising a state change because the change is deep in state, and I'm not successfully creating a new state object, I'm probably referencing old instances somehow.

**reducer code**

Below is my bungled attempt to force a new state object. I'm assuming it's not working because my components are not being re-rendered. It also seems very inelegant.

```
let initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    data: {
        elementIds: ['name', 'email'],
        elements: {
            'name': {'id': 'name', 'value':'ben'},
            'email': {'id':'email', 'value':'ben@test.com'},
        },
    },
    error: false
}

function formReducer(state = initialState, action = null) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.CHANGE_ELEMENT_VALUE:
            let newData = Object.assign(state.data)
            newData.elements[action.id].value = action.value
            return {...state, data: newData}

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default formReducer;
```

Comment: The first think I've noticed is that you're misusing `Object.assign`. If you test it, you could see that `newData === state.data`, this is because the first argument is the target. Generally speaking, you would always have this "issue" of deeply cloning objects (which becomes uglier if the structure is dynamic), so the answers below may be useful to you. I personally, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/icepick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make use of `immutability-helper npm package` and update your values in your reducer

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

let initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    data: {
        elementIds: ['name', 'email'],
        elements: {
            'name': {'id': 'name', 'value':'ben'},
            'email': {'id':'email', 'value':'ben@test.com'},
        },
    },
    error: false
}

function formReducer(state = initialState, action = null) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.CHANGE_ELEMENT_VALUE:
            return update(state, {
                data : {
                    elements: {
                         [action.id]: {
                               value: {
                                    $set: 'new value'
                                }
                          }
                    }
                }
            })

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default formReducer;
```

> `update()` provides simple syntactic sugar around this pattern to make
>   writing this code easier. While the syntax takes a little getting used
>   to (though it's inspired by MongoDB's query language) there's no
>   redundancy, it's statically analyzable and it's not much more typing
>   than the mutative version.

Comment: Thanks @shubham-khatri. Do you or anyone else have an opinion on whether this is better than the deep-extend option that linkiwi suggested above?

Answer (score 1):

`Object.assign` only operates one level deep; i.e. it does not recursively clone the entire object tree. So, your top-level object is cloned but it doesn't trigger a rerender since your reducer mutates a value deep in the cloned object.

I would recommend looking into the `deep-extend` package and updating your state as follows:

```
import extend from 'deep-extend';

...

return extend(state, {
  elements: {
    [key]: value
  }
});
```

Comment: This looks handy. Should I be concerned by any performance penalties, or concerns about my state structure, and the fact that I'm having to replicate a whole part of the tree on every key stroke, just to change one value by one character?